# Call C function in matlab-simulink/stateflow

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I created a C function in test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>


int Test()
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("C:\\workspace\\test.txt", "rw");
    fprintf(fp, "test hello world");
    fclose(fp);
    return 10;
}
```

And I defined a state in stateflow of simulink. I used

```
en: Test();
```

I specified the file in both Tools->Open Simulation Target->Custom Code->Include List of additional and Include Custom C Code in generated (using absolute path and file name)
When I tried to run the model, I got parser error:
en: Test();
         ^
Function named 'Test' is not a Stateflow Function.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it done by my own.
In the "Include Custom C Code in generated:"->Header file tab,
I should specify my header file as

```
#include "test.h"
```

instead of

```
test.h
```

And c file should be specified in "Include list of additional"->Source files as

```
test.c
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding reference to an online example for adding custom C code to Stateflow that will help other users who run into similar issues:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1727V/